# How do I restrict special character, underscore, space in name field of the form(input tag)?

Tags: html

I have a html form and I don't want to allow any special characters, underscore to the field. How can I make it possible?

```
    <!--field for username-->
    <div  class="form-group" >
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input type="text" name="uname" pattern=".{6,225}" title="Enter full name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full name" required/>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can change `pattern=".{6,225}"` to `pattern="[a-zA-Z]{6,225}"` But *don't forget to check in the back-end*

Comment: How can I allow numbers? It is not allowing numbers also @Seblor

Comment: This is a simple regex, you can try it on regex101.com. for numbers, change it to `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,225}"`

Comment: Thanks it worked.. if I want to allow space in between the string? @Seblor

Comment: Then you just have to add a space inside the brackets (after the `9`)

Answer (score 0):

You should attach to input element onchange function that will check if inserted value is _ or any other character that you do not want. If it is a character that you do not want that do not allow input to receive that character by saying e.preventDefault();